# Application doesnt display my Editor/Display Templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two display templates in the folder Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates called:

ShowMCQViewModel 
ShowMatrixViewModel

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Data)
    {
        <p>@Model.Data.Count()</p>
        <p>@item.GetType()</p>
        Html.DisplayFor(x => item);
    }
```

The Count() method returns: 2
and GetType() returns: MvcApplication3.Models.ViewModels.Question.ShowMCQViewModel

But the View does not display anything from the Display Template..

I did the exact same thing in another Web Application, the models were just in the Models folder, and it worked fine.

Do i need to set up paths or something?

Thanks

Comment: Hrm, have you tried changing the name of your template to MvcApplication3.Models.ViewModels.Question.ShowMCQViewModel.cshtml? Maybe try moving them to the Models folder instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@Model.Data.Count()</p>
    <p>@item.GetType()</p>
    Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Data);
}
```

You will loop through the Model and pick each Data item that will be displayed using ShowMCQViewModel template